# React Query Key Factory Error: 'queryKey' does not exist

Tags: reactjs, react-query, tanstackreact-query

I'm using the `@luke-morales/query-key-factory` library. I'm trying to create a sign in mutation like below. But I'm getting this error when doing `queryKeys.user.signIn.queryKey,` when invalidating. What might be the problem?

### Error

```
Property 'queryKey' does not exist on type 'DynamicFactoryOutput<["user", "signIn"], (credentials: SignInCredentials) => { queryKey: [string, SignInCredentials]; }, { queryKey: [string, SignInCredentials]; }>'.
```

### Code

```
const userKeys = createQueryKeys("user", {
  signIn: (credentials: SignInCredentials) => ({
    queryKey: ["signIn", credentials],
  }),
});

export const queryKeys = mergeQueryKeys(userKeys);
```

```
import { useMutation, useQueryClient } from "@tanstack/react-query";
import { postSignIn } from "api/user";
import queryKeys from "./queryKeys";

export default function useSignInMutation() {
  const navigate = useNavigate();
  const queryClient = useQueryClient();

  return useMutation({
    mutationFn: postSignIn,
    onSuccess: ({ data }) => {
      queryClient.invalidateQueries({
        queryKey: queryKeys.user.signIn.queryKey, // Error: `queryKey` does not exist
      });

      const { accessToken, refreshToken } = data;

      localStorage.setItem("accessToken", accessToken);
      localStorage.setItem("refreshToken", refreshToken);

      navigate("/");
    },
  });
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When looking at the documentation and examples, it seems that you forgot to use a function to call your query keys. See the `setQueryData` in the example below.

```
export function useUpdateTodo() {
  const queryClient = useQueryClient();

  return useMutation(updateTodo, {
    onSuccess(newTodo) {
      queryClient.setQueryData(queries.todos.detail(newTodo.id).queryKey, newTodo);

      // invalidate all the list queries
      queryClient.invalidateQueries({
        queryKey: queries.todos.list._def,
        refetchActive: false,
      });
    },
  });
};
```

So applying this to your code:

```
export default function useSignInMutation() {
  const navigate = useNavigate();
  const queryClient = useQueryClient();

  return useMutation({
    mutationFn: postSignIn,
    onSuccess: ({ data }, variables) => {
      queryClient.invalidateQueries({
        queryKey: queryKeys.user.signIn(variables).queryKey,
      });

     //...
    },
  });
}
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing out. The docs(https://tanstack.com/query/v4/docs/react/community/lukemorales-query-key-factory) seemed to be doing `queryKeys.todos.list.queryKey`.
```
export const todosKeys = createQueryKeys('todos', {
  detail: (todoId: string) => [todoId],
  list: (filters: TodoFilters) => ({
    queryKey: [{ filters }],
    queryFn: (ctx) => api.getTodos({ filters, page: ctx.pageParam }),
  }),
});

const mutation = useMutation({
  mutationFn: completeTodo,
  onSuccess: () => {
    queryClient.invalidateQueries({ queryKey: queryKeys.todos.list.queryKey })
  },
});
```